# Javascript Populate select with json data in ES6 (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, json

I have some data in json format that I would like to add to my select.

Here is the data:

```
 {
    "timezones": 
    {
        "country": "Africa",
        "tz": "Africa/Abidjan"
    },
    {
        "country": "America",
        "tz": "America/Anguilla"
    }
}
```

Here is the current select:

```
<select>

    <optgroup label="Africa">
        <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Adak</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="America">
        <option value="America/Adak">Anguilla</option>
    </optgroup>

</select>
```

How can I populate the select from the json data instead of hard coding it without jQuery ?

Comment: Your object throws syntax error.

Comment: 'timeszones' should be an array, or every entry should have a index.

Comment: 1. Fix the data/JSON as of right now it's not valid. 2. Why the `<optgroup>` elements? Will there be multiple entries? 3. Where is the text of the `<option>`s (_Adak, Anguilla_) coming from? It's not in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `appendChild` method in combination with `.forEach` method.

```js
let obj={
    "timezones": 
    [{
        "country": "Africa",
        "tz": "Africa/Abidjan"
    },
    {
        "country": "America",
        "tz": "America/Anguilla"
    }]
};
let select=document.getElementById('countrySelect');
obj.timezones.forEach(function(item){
  let newOptGroup=document.createElement('optgroup');
  newOptGroup.label=item.country;
  let option=document.createElement('option');
  option.value=item.tz;
  option.text=item.tz;
  newOptGroup.appendChild(option);
  select.appendChild(newOptGroup);
});
```

```html
<select id="countrySelect">

</select>
```

Comment: The text is not the same as the value (and not included in the data/question at all)

Comment: @Andreas, I know, but I give the OP the solution how to create his select element which is the main part.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you're JSON data is not valid. 'timezones' should be an array, or has an index on every object.

Data

```
let data = {
  "timezones": [
  {
      "country": "Africa",
      "tz": "Africa/Abidjan"
  },
  {
      "country": "America",
      "tz": "America/Anguilla"
  }]
}
```

I would populate the options as follow:

```
data.timeszones.forEach(function(timezone) {
  let optionGroup = document.createElement('optgroup');
      optionGroup.setAttribute('label', timezone.country);

  let option = document.createElement('option');
      option.setAttribute('value', timezone.tz);

  optionGroup.appendChild(option);
  document.getElementById('selectionList').appendChild(optionGroup);
});
```

And obvisously, don't forget to set an ID to your  element.

```
<select id='selectionList'>
    <optgroup label="Africa">
        <option value="Africa/Abidjan">Adak</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="America">
        <option value="America/Adak">Anguilla</option>
    </optgroup> 
</select>
```